# Java: Calculating perfomance per second

Tags: java

I have a thread pool that performs some heavy operations concurrently, the following is my code

ExampleCompute.java

```
class ExampleCompute {
   private List<long> allData = new ArrayList<long>();
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

   public calculate() {
      for(int i=0; i<myData.size; i++) {
        MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(myData.get(i));
        Future<long> currentDataPoint = executor.submit(worker);
        allData.add(currentDataPoint);
      }

      executor.shutdown();
      while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
      }
   }
}
```

What I am attempting to do is print to the screen how many operations are finishing per second every N seconds.

For example

```
// Every 10 seconds do the following
System.out.println("Thread pool is completing 533 calculation per second");
```

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: There are simple approach and complex approach. A simple approach would be to get the worker to set an update once the job is finished. But since timing or job status got nothing to do with the business logic in running the task, you can use AOP cutpoints to intercept the finishing event. The AOP method maybe overkill but its the right way forward, I think.

Comment: Aop will hit the performance .For time metrics it should not increase over all complexity of task execution.Do you want the time is average or for that instant time.If it is average then on job completion you can calculate avg.

Comment: That instant in time.  If I want the average I'll probably log the data and run a query later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use before and after method to track the time

```
public class TrackingThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final ThreadLocal<Long> startTime = new ThreadLocal<Long>();
    private volatile long totalTime;
    private volatile long totalTasks;

    public TrackingThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory factory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, factory);
    }

    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
        startTime.set(new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.get().longValue();

        synchronized (this) {
            totalTime += time;
            ++totalTasks;
        }

        super.afterExecute(r, t);
    }
}
```